# Priorities in a select query with oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I use the following query for a report.

```
      SELECT P.PIECE_ID,spd.IS_MAIN_DEFECT,spd.PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID
      FROM piece P , STY_PIECE_DEFECT spd ,STY_DEFECT_CATALOGUE sdc ,piece_history ph , 
      piece_history_out pho, PLANT_CONFIG pc,STY_QUALITY sq 
      (...join and where clauses)
      GROUP BY P.PIECE_ID,spd.IS_MAIN_DEFECT,spd.PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID ORDER BY 1 desc
```

The output :

[image]

But I want to see the following result in my output ;

IS_MAIN_DEFECT will be checked as a priority.

If it is 'Y' then 
I will only see that row in the table
else it is 'N' then 
I will only see that min(piece_defect_num_id) row in the table.

For example :  I need to see that piece_defect_num_id as 141,900  for '20190158GA' ,

If all IS_MAIN_DEFECT values are 'N' for '20190158GA' then I need to see that piece_defect_num_id as 141,476.

Comment: `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.  `JOIN`.

Comment: what about something like `min(piece_defect_num_id) over (partition by piece_id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an analytic function could be helpful in this case

```
  SELECT P.PIECE_ID
  , spd.IS_MAIN_DEFECT
  ,spd.PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID
  -- check if defect is the main one or not
  , CASE WHEN spd.is_main_defect = 'N' THEN
      min(spd.piece_defect_num_id) OVER (partition by p.PIECE_ID)
    ELSE NULL END as min_defect

  FROM piece P , STY_PIECE_DEFECT spd ,STY_DEFECT_CATALOGUE sdc ,piece_history ph , 
  piece_history_out pho, PLANT_CONFIG pc,STY_QUALITY sq 
  (...join and where clauses)
  GROUP BY P.PIECE_ID,spd.IS_MAIN_DEFECT,spd.PIECE_DEFECT_NUM_ID ORDER BY 1 desc
```

It's hard to provide a workable query without full table/query definitions, however an example could be found [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ff7fe6bb9f76681c1d1741ce582b585)

To reiterate the advice mentioned by @Gordon Linoff - try using ANSI JOIN syntax if possible